# Cast deleted QOjbect* from QVariant cause seg fault in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt

The following code cause segmentation fault when using Qt5 but it won't be a problem when using Qt4.

```cpp
auto a = new QObject(); // need to be subclass of QObject, other class won't happen
auto v = QVariant::fromValue<QObject*>(a);
delete a;
auto p = qvariant_cast<QObject *>(v);
```

The use case in my project is unit test using `QSignalSpy`:

```cpp
...
// I need to check objects removed from model work as intended
// and objectRemoved signal delete object right after event received
QSignalSpy spy(&model, SIGNAL(objectRemoved(Object*)));
...
assertEqual(spy[0][0].value<Object*>(), myobject); // seg fault
```

I have checked the implementation of qvariant_cast are different between [Qt4](https://github.com/qt/qt/blob/4.8/src/corelib/kernel/qvariant.h) and [Qt5](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.14.1/src/corelib/kernel/qvariant.h), but I can't really understand the source code...

The question is

1. The pointer is all I need, not the data, is there a way I can retrieve it?
2. Should I even do it (cast a deleted pointer)
3. Any advise for my unit test, should I just remove it or there are better solution?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you play with pointers? Just check the content of your model after deletion. For example, check for the row count.

Comment: For what it's worth `qvariant_cast<QObject *>` (actually in `QMetaObject::cast`) will dereference a non-null pointer to check its type: `return (obj && obj->metaObject()->inherits(this)) ? obj : nullptr;`.  Hence the segfault.

Comment: @vahancho The project did check row count. I think it want to make sure removed object is expected. I will remove the check from unit test, thanks!

Comment: @G.M. Thanks point out, I finally trace to the segfault part [source](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.14.1/src/corelib/kernel/qmetaobject.cpp). need more time to understand why Qt does so much for type conversion...